# nsis uninstall, FileRead returns null

Tags: nsis, uninstallation

I've written an NSIS installer that on an uninstall has to remove all files it installed.

I've written a list of installed files to a manifest file on install and that works correctly.

On the uninstall however, a FileRead of the manifest returns nothing; it still reads every record of the file but the variable which should contain the line content is null.  Funny thing is the code works in the un.onInit Function but not in the Uninstall section.  Can anyone enlighten me as to why this is so?

Here is the function:

```
StrCpy $R6 "$myIni\manifest.pf"

FileOpen $6 "$R6" r

FileRead $6 "$line"

${Do} 
    Delete /REBOOTOK "$INSTDIR$line"

    IfErrors fail continue
fail: 
    DetailPrint "Delete failed, file=$INSTDIR$line"

    MessageBox MB_ICONSTOP "path=$line"

    Abort
continue:
    DetailPrint "Delete $INSTDIR$line"

    FileRead $6 "$line"
${LoopUntil} $line == ""

FileClose $6
```

Thanks in advance,

Steven

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for [`FileRead`](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Chapter4.html#4.9.5.3) is:

```
FileRead handle user_var(output) [maxlen]
```

You are calling it with `"$line"`: a string interpolated with the value of the variable `$line` inside instead of a variable.

Replace `"$line"` with `$line` on your `FilreRead` calls and it should be ok.

Comment: No sorry, not OK.

The code works, with or without quotes, in the .onInit function, the Main section and also the un.onInit function, which is not where the routine has to run.

It does not work in the Uninstall section and unfortunately for me, that is where it needs to be.

Thanks for the suggestion but it's not fixed the problem.